# Error al programar un JOB en SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy programando un JOB (**DEPURACION_TRAMITE**) en un servidor Remoto, me sale el siguiente resultado (*no programado*) en este campo: *Siguiente Ejecución* visto desde el monitor de *JOB's*:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Simplemente está muerto, no hay mensajes de error de ejecución, simplemente no se ejecuta, no sé si sea un problema de usuario o roles sobre la base de datos o servidor (manejamos un dominio de usuarios de red de windows).

Y me sale el siguiente mensaje de error cuando ejecuto los pasos manualmente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya he revisado artículos de internet, pero no se acercan al problema que tengo, por que con la misma configuración (fechas de inicio, periodo, habilitación de la tarea, etc) en un servidor local funcionan correctamente.

**NOTA**: Los demás job's también fueron creados por mi usuario y pues también "lógicamente" están en el mismo estado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que el error es claro: **"SQL SERVER AGENT is not currently running..."** ve al SQL Server Configuration Manager y revisa que este corriendo el Agente.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con ello debería ejecutar tu job. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias, ese era el problema.

Comment: De nada, me serviría de mucho que des como válida la respuesta, o en todo caso un voto positivo. Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Tienes que iniciar el agente por medio del configuration manager o por sql server management studio, para poder ejecutar tus jobs, el error dice que el agente no esta corriendo

[image: Iniciar agente management studio]
[image: Iniciar agente configuration manager]

Comment: Gracias, el problema era precisamente que el agente no estaba corriendo, aunque no pude entrar al administrador de configuración desde el management studio.

Comment: No se puede entrar al configuration manager desde el SSMS, ese lo tienes que buscar en Programas>Microsoft SQL Server XXX>Configuration tools> SQL Server Configuration Manager. Solo te ponía las dos formas de como iniciar el agente.